# WPF Mutually Exclusive Listboxes

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have an app that has a ListBox of ListBoxes.  I would like to make the InnerList boxes mutually exclusive.  My ViewModel has a collection Foos which have a description, an IsSelected property and a collections Bars which have a name and IsSelected property.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos { /* code removed for brevity */ }
}

public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public string Description { /* code removed for brevity */ }
     public ObservableCollection<Bar> Bars { /* code removed for brevity */ }
     public bool IsSelected { /* code removed for brevity */ }
}

public class Bar : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public string Name { /* code removed for brevity */ }
     public bool IsSelected { /* code removed for brevity */ }
}
```

Below is a part of my MainWindow whose DataContext is set to MyViewModel.  This ListBox's ItemsSource property is bound using `ItemsSource={Binding Path=Foos}` and in the template for this ListBox is an inner ListBox which is bound using `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Bars}"`.  A, B, and C are Foos' Descriptions.  The items contained in them are Bar's Names.

```
|--------------------------|
| A |--------------------| |
|   | Item 1             | |
|   | Item 2             | |
|   | Item 3             | |
|   |--------------------| |
|                          |
| B |--------------------| |
|   | Item X             | |
|   | Item Y             | |
|   | Item Z             | |
|   |--------------------| |
|                          |
| C |--------------------| |
|   | Item l             | |
|   | Item m             | |
|   |--------------------| |
|--------------------------|
```

I need to make it so a user can only select a single item out of any of the Bars.  So, if the user selects Item 1 from Foo A then selects Item X from Foo B then Item 1 should be deselected.

I also need to bind the selected item to a TextBox control elsewhere on the window, but 1 thing a time I suppose.

Doing this in code and selection changed events is not an option.  I'd prefer to keep this using XAML only.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
Following Moonshield's advice I've come up with this, but it still isn't completely working.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     private Bar _selectedBar;

     public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos { /* code removed for brevity */ }
     public Bar SelectedBar 
     { 
          get { return _selectedBar; }
          set 
          {
              _selectedBar = null;
              NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedBar");

              _selectedBar = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedBar");
          }
     }    
}
```

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbFoos" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Foos}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedBar}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="Foo: " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Bars}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}">
                                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            </ListBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably to add a SelectedBar property to your MyViewModel class and bind the SelectedItem property of the listboxes to that. This only allows one item to be selected at once, and provides you with something to bind your textbox to later.

You can then set a binding (OneWayToSource) on the IsSelected property of each ListBoxItem (via ItemContainerStyle perhaps) to update the IsSelected property of each bar. To update the IsSelected property of the Foo objects, set a binding to the listbox's SelectedItem with a valueconverter to check if it is null.

Edit:

SelectedItem Property (implementing Dan's fix):

```
protected Bar selectedItem;
public Bar SelectedItem{
    get
    {
        return selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        selectedItem = null;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");

        selectedItem = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
    }
```

ListBoxItem with Binding (assuming ListBoxItem DataContext is Bar viewmodel):

```
<ListBoxItem IsSelected="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

Edit - fixes to your code:

I managed to get your code working. Two issues I found:

1. The reason items weren't appearing to select was that you'd re-templated the ListBoxItems populated with Bar objects, so there was no highlight style when an item was selected - fixed this by setting the ItemTemplate instead, which templates the content of the item rather than overriding the whole template.
2. Instead of binding the SelectedItem of one of the nested ListBoxes to the SelectedItem index of the parent and then binding that to the viewmodel, I changed the binding to bind directly to the viewmodel, which fixed the multiple-selection issue.

   ```
   <ListBox x:Name="lbFoos" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Foos}"> <!--Removed SelectedItem binding.-->
       <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
               <Setter Property="Template">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                           <StackPanel>
                               <TextBlock Text="Foo: " />
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                               <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Bars}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedBar, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"><!--Changed binding to bind directly to ViewModel-->
                                   <ListBox.ItemTemplate><!--Set ItemTemplated rather than ControlTemplate-->
                                       <DataTemplate>
                                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                       </DataTemplate> 
                                   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                       <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                           <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                                       </Style>
                                   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                               </ListBox>
                           </StackPanel>
                       </ControlTemplate>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
           </Style>
       </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   </ListBox>
   ```

Comment: One caveat I've run into is that if the SelectedItem property of the list box is bound to a property and the property takes on a value that's not in the list, it will not cause the selected item to be visually deselected.  I ended up hacking around this by modifying the setter of the SelectedObject ViewModel property so that it would pulse a notify property changed of 'null' between updates.  This would correctly cause the list boxes to deselect.

Comment: @Moonshield This sounds good.  Can you give me a small XAML snippet of how to do the OneWayToSource binding?

Comment: @Dan - Good catch on that one, and an interesting solution.

Comment: @Adam - Updated my answer with a couple of examples.

Comment: @Moonshield Thanks, still having some problems.  Updated question with my XAML.

Comment: @Adam - Updated my answer with a couple of fixes to your code.

Comment: @Moonshield Awesome, you rock.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want one item to be selected at any time then having an `IsSelected` property is pointless. Instead you should have a container property which holds the currently selected item (as per Moonshield's suggestion). This model implies that only one can be selected, whereas your existing model implies that many can be selected. Ultimately, the individual instances of Foo probably don't need to know that they've been selected anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding to SelectedItem, try binding to SelectedValue instead. I have a similar situation with two DataGrids that bind ItemsSource to two different ICollectionView properties in my ViewModel. These ICollectionView properties use the same ObservableCollection as their original source, and are mutually exclusive through a filter using a property of MyType. (I.e. One filters on one value of the property and the other ICollectionView filters on a different value of the same property.)

I have a property in my ViewModel called SelectedMyType of type MyType that is bound to the SelectedValue property of each DataGrid. When an item is selected from either DataGrid, any previously selected item is deselected.