# WPF Single selection between two ListBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, mvvm, listbox

I'm having the following problem: I have two `ListBox`, with two different `ItemSource`, but both of them have the same `binding` for the `SelectedItem`, because I was trying to perform a single selection between these two lists.

Here's an image that better shows the problem:

[image: First list in red. Second list in black.]

What would I like to do? Every time I select one item from the first list (in red), it should **deselect** the `SelectedItem` from the second list (in black), and vice versa. That's why I'm using the same `binding` for both of them.
I really don't know if it's the better way to do it, but it should work like that.

Could you help me?

Comment: I think you should use a custom attached behavior instead...

Comment: @FelicePollano But how could I do that? Would you have some code to help?

Comment: This kinda relates to questions like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293253/wpf-mutually-exclusive-listboxes

Comment: @dowhilefor I will check this question and see if it works.

Comment: @Clemens The type is 'Version', one of my custom classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I had to do was at first pass `null` to the property and notify the changing, and then I passed the real value to the property and notified the changing to the view.
Like that:

```
protected Bar selectedItem;
public Bar SelectedItem{
    get
    {
        return selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        selectedItem = null;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");

        selectedItem = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
    }
```

I got this answer and example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293253/wpf-mutually-exclusive-listboxes).

Comment: This fix works really well. Simple but working.

Only thing I can think of that might go wrong is when another thread tries to acces the SelectedItem at the moment it's set to null.

Answer (score 20):

Try using `SelectedValue` instead, this will sop the behaviour you are seeing

```
 <ListBox SelectedValue="{Binding MySelectedItem}" />
```

It seems that `SelectedItem` does not deselect is the selected item is not found in the list, But `SelectedValue` does seem to deselect it, not sure why

You can see the diffence in this sample app:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="184" Width="208" x:Name="UI">
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <TextBlock Text="SelectedValue" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="60" >
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemSource1}" SelectedValue="{Binding MySelectedValue}" Width="100" />
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemSource2}" SelectedValue="{Binding MySelectedValue}" Width="100" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="SelectedItem" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="60"  >
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemSource1}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" Width="100" />
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemSource2}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" Width="100" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private CustomObject _mySelectedItem;
    private CustomObject _mySelectedValue;
    private ObservableCollection<CustomObject> _items = new ObservableCollection<CustomObject>();
    private ObservableCollection<CustomObject> _items2 = new ObservableCollection<CustomObject>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyItemSource1.Add(new CustomObject { Name = "Stack" });
        MyItemSource1.Add(new CustomObject { Name = "Overflow" });
        MyItemSource2.Add(new CustomObject { Name = "Stack" });
        MyItemSource2.Add(new CustomObject { Name = "Overflow" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CustomObject> MyItemSource1
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CustomObject> MyItemSource2
    {
        get { return _items2; }
        set { _items2 = value; }
    }

    public CustomObject MySelectedItem
    {
        get { return _mySelectedItem; }
        set { _mySelectedItem = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem"); }
    }

    public CustomObject MySelectedValue
    {
        get { return _mySelectedValue; }
        set { _mySelectedValue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MySelectedValue"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}

public class CustomObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tryied using `SelectedValue`, but it didn't work. I think it's because I'm calling another method inside `property's set` that needs a value different from `null`, and if I use `SelectedValue`, somehow it tryied to set null to my property. I don't know if I'm clear with this comment.

Comment: this works, but now I started to think why I need SelectedItem then?!