# Dynamically Create TextBlock and TextBox in XAML WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

My Question Is I have a grid where number of `TextBlock` and `TextBox` will vary as per the `ComboBox` `SelectedItem` Change

So, what I want is that I have written a function for get the details of the `TextBlock` and `TextBox`.

**C# Function**

```
public void GetAdditionalAttributes()
{
    using (Entities _entities = new Entities())
    {
        var attributeAll = (from c in _entities.AdditionalAttributeValues
                            where c.DeviceID == 35
                            select new AttributesClass { AttributeValue = c.AdditionalAttributeValue1, AttributeName = c.AdditionalAttribute.Name }).ToList();
        DeviceAttributes = new ObservableCollection<AttributesClass>(attributeAll);
    }
}
```

Now In the XAML I was trying:

```
<Style x:Key="AdditionalAttributeDisplay"
        TargetType="Grid"
        x:Name="AdditionalAttributeDisplay"
        >
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                    Value="{Binding DeviceAttributes}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=DeviceTypeComboBox}"
                                Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                            Value="{Binding DeviceAttributes}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

But I don't know how to create a `TextBlock` or `TextBox` with `ItemSource` binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `ItemTemplate` of your `ItemsControl`.

```
  <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
     <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ItemContainerTemplate>
                 <Grid>
                     <TextBox Width="100" Height="20" Text={Binding AttributeName}/>
                 </Grid>
             </ItemContainerTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
  </Style>
```

In above snippet replace `PropertyName` with `DeviceAttributes` member you want

Comment: But How can I bind the name or values to TextBox and TextBlock In there?

Comment: `Text="{Binding PropertyName}"`

Comment: You have to replace the PropertyName with your DataContext Property

Comment: and In my GRID
`<Grid Style="{StaticResource AdditionalAttributeDisplay}">
 </Grid>`

right?

Comment: Use snoop control and snoop the ItemsControl to find the DataContext. You will get the Properties of your DataContext in snoop. Bind it to the Textbox. It has no connection with Grid style

Comment: Sorry I'm totally new to WPF and have no Idea about whatever you are talking.

Comment: Replace PropertyName with AttributeName. I have updated the answer

Comment: I have got this so far,

but I'm talking about the place where I will be display this Data in my Grid

Comment: pls send your sample app to vimalkumar_ck@hotmail.com. I can help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057238/how-to-make-a-generic-selecteditem-for-all-combobox

Thought might help in this one as well